# Using multiple sliders with Plotly Dashboard scatter plot 3D

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to create three filters for my 3D scatter plot.

Based on what I read here: https://medium.com/left-join/building-a-plotly-dashboard-with-dynamic-sliders-in-python-f5cf84161dc5 and here: https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/ I should put only the sliders and call them in `@app.callback` as a list with parameters.

I tried like this:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Iris samples filtered by petal width'),
    dcc.Graph(id="3d-scatter-plot-x-graph"),
    html.P("Petal Width:"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider',
        min=0, max=2.5, step=0.1,
        marks={0: '0', 2.5: '2.5'},
        value=[0.5, 2]
    ),
    html.P("Sepal Length:"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider',
        min=0, max=2.5, step=0.1,
        marks={0: '0', 2.5: '2.5'},
        value=[0.5, 2]
    ),
    html.P("Sepal Width:"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider',
        min=0, max=5, step=0.1,
        marks={0: '0', 5: '5'},
        value=[0.5, 4.5]
    ),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("3d-scatter-plot-x-graph", "figure"),
    [Input("3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider", "value"),
    Input("3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider", "value"),
    Input("3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider", "value")])
def update_bar_chart(slider_x, slider_y, slider_z):
    df = px.data.iris()  # replace with your own data source
    low_x, high_x = slider_x
    low_y, high_y = slider_y
    low_z, high_z = slider_z
    mask = (df.petal_width > low_x) & (df.petal_width < high_x) & (df.sepal_length > low_y) & (df.sepal_length < high_y)

    fig = px.scatter_3d(df[mask],
                        x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                        color="species", hover_data=['petal_width'])
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But I got nothing (empty plot with sliders)

[image]

And I didn't got any errors.

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: You mentioned a bar graph, but called for a scatter plot... The reason you see no data is that there are no observations (rows) that meet the requirements you have set. For the field `Sepal Length`, you set the values to the range 0.5 to 2. There are no rows that meet this requirement. (The range is between 4.3 and 7.9.) If you change `value` for `dcc.RangeSlider` for `Sepal Length` to `value = [4.3, 7.9]` you'll get your 3d scatter plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [@Kat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329073/kat)'s comment, you have to change the ranges and as I see `Sepal Width` slider does not take any effect, you have to add it to the update function.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Iris samples filtered by petal width'),
    dcc.Graph(id="3d-scatter-plot-x-graph"),
    html.P("Petal Width:"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider',
        min=0, max=2.5, step=0.1,
        marks={0: '0', 2.5: '2.5'},
        value=[0.5, 2]
    ),
    html.P("Sepal Length:"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider',
        min=4.3, max=7.9, step=0.1,
        marks={0: '0', 2.5: '2.5'},
        value=[4.3, 7.9]
    ),
    html.P("Sepal Width:"),
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider',
        min=2, max=4, step=0.1,
        marks={0: '0', 5: '5'},
        value=[1.5, 4]
    ),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("3d-scatter-plot-x-graph", "figure"),
    [Input("3d-scatter-plot-x-range-slider", "value"),
    Input("3d-scatter-plot-y-range-slider", "value"),
    Input("3d-scatter-plot-z-range-slider", "value")])
def update_bar_chart(slider_x, slider_y, slider_z):
    df = px.data.iris()  # replace with your own data source
    low_x, high_x = slider_x
    low_y, high_y = slider_y
    low_z, high_z = slider_z
    mask = (df.petal_width > low_x) & (df.petal_width < high_x) & (df.sepal_length > low_y) & (df.sepal_length < high_y) & (df.sepal_width > low_z) & (df.sepal_width < high_z)

    fig = px.scatter_3d(df[mask],
                        x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                        color="species", hover_data=['petal_width'])
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```